# Failed to start high performance web server and reverse proxy server nginx

Tags: angular, ubuntu, ssl, nginx, digital-ocean

UPDATE - I got these error logs:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown "request_url" variable
Aug 19 01:14:58 nginx[4890]: nginx: 
configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript 
text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##
```

The "request url" part of the error could be in my sites-enabled/default file in the location block near the bottom:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    server_name         www.domainname;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

            return 301 https://www.hobyn.co$request_url;
```

---

ORIGINAL QUESTION - I get the failed to start high performance web server and reverse proxy server when running:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

to restart nginx after making the server block configurations below to my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file.  My angular app is being served in /var/www/html:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    server_name         www.mydomainname;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/****.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/****.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;


location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

            return 301 https://www.mydomainname$request_url;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error with this configuration here:

```
server {
    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    server_name domainname www.domainname;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_redirect    off;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic. See: 
      https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}
}

server {

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name hobyn.co www.hobyn.co;
  return 301 https://hobyn.co$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm tring fix. and last. Ubuntu wsl missing  dependenci. Try:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install -y git
$ git clone https://github.com/DamionGans/ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script.git
$ cd ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script/
$ bash ubuntu-wsl2-systemd-script.sh
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).